# How to compare array values in a bash script?

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, passwords

I am trying to generate a random password with certain requirements.

> Minimum 8 characters
>
> Atleast 1 lowercase letter
>
> atleast 1 uppercase letter
>
> atleast 1 number
>
> must have 1 special character

Atm I am trying to compare a random passphrase, that I generate, with the number array so that I can determine if a number exists in the generated passphrase. After getting this to work I want to use a similar check for the other arrays (lowercase, uppercase and special chars).

However when I run my script `if $phrase[1] = F and $num[1] = 1` my code will echo `"fine"` instead of echoing `false`... the two values are not equal so I do not know why its not working?

```
#!/bin/bash
#SET ARRAYS
num=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )
all=( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )

echo

#GENERATE RANDOM PASSPHRASE
for (( i=0; i<8; i++ ))
do
phrase[$i]=${all[$RANDOM%62]}
        for (( j=0; j<10; j++ ))
        do
                #CHECK IF A VALUE FROM $NUM ARRAY IS IN $PHRASE
                if [ ${phrase[$i]}==${num[$j]} ]
                then
                echo phrase[$i]: ${phrase[$i]} #debug
                echo num[$j]: ${num[$j]}       #debug
                echo fine                     
                else
                echo false
                fi
        done
done

printf "%s" "Phrase: ${phrase[@]}" && echo
echo

echo ${num[@]}
echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around the `==` operator. Otherwise, bash only sees one large word and tests

```
[ -n "${phrase[$i]}==${num[$j]}" ]
```